# Custom UITableViewCell issue in UITableView

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I have an app with a UIViewController containing a UITableView using a custom table view cell. I have used the same custom table view cell with UITableViewControllers successfully but this time it's a UITableView in a UIViewController. My first thoughts were that it really should be no different. However, for some reason, in my cellForRowAtIndexPath, upon initial loading, 'cell' is not nil, as it should be, so the code to instantiate the custom cell is never called.

I've created the custom cell both by using interface builder and by hand coding it with identical results. The only noticible difference is that the code works correctly when using it with a UITableViewController but fails when using it with a UIView containing a UITableView.

I have verified that my cell identifier is properly configured and my datasource and delegates are properly set in my UIViewController. The custom cell has its subclass properly set.

```
-(FaveCell*)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

FaveCell *cell = (FaveCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellID];
if(cell == nil){
    // this line of code is never reached
    cell = [[FaveCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellID];
}

/* code to load controls

...

*/

return cell;
}
```

So, when the code enters cellForRowAtIndexPath for the first time, 'cell' should be nil, but it's not. Again, the only noticable difference being UIView/UITableView vs UITableViewController. Does this make sense to anyone? Can anyone offer a solution? Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a NIB for your custom cell?

Comment: Yes, there is a nib for the custom cell

Comment: Does your table otherwise look and behave correctly, and the only symptom is that the `if(cell == nil)` code does not get entered?

Comment: Yes, in fact, when I remove the check for a nil cell, everything works as it should

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However, for some reason, in my `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, upon initial loading, `cell` is not `nil`, as it should be, so the code to instantiate the custom cell is never called.

This is because `UITableView` became smarter as of iOS 5.0: if you tell it what kind of cells you want by specifying the custom cell type, it creates them for you, so the `if(cell == nil)` code is indeed never entered. From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/tableview_iphone/CreateConfigureTableView/CreateConfigureTableView.html):

> If the `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` method asks for a cell that’s defined in a storyboard, the method always returns a valid cell. If there is not a recycled cell waiting to be reused, the method creates a new one using the information in the storyboard itself. This eliminates the need to check the return value for `nil` and create a cell manually.

Comment: That explains why the version I created using a nib didn't work properly. But I also created a custom cell by hard coding. This produced the same results. The hard coded version worked properly in the table view controller, but not the table view.

Comment: It seems that not checking for a nil cell would conflict with dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier

Comment: @Pheepster I keep the check in my code, just in case Apple decides to do something new (and incompatible) with their implementation of `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` method. As long as instantiation is the only thing that you do inside that `if`, it wouldn't hurt (unless you rely on the specific initializer called inside `if`, and that is *not* the same initializer called by the table view).